# How do I use SqlConnection and DataContext together?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a slightly overengineered code and need to use `DataContext` together with `SqlConnection`. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292288.aspx) says

> If you provide an open connection, the DataContext will not close it. Therefore, do not instantiate a DataContext with an open connection unless you have a good reason to do this.

In my code I'll effectively have this:

```
using( var connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) ) {
    connection.Open();
    // some action
    using( var context = new DataContext( connection ) ) {
       //some action with the context object
    }
    //more action with the connection
}
```

To me it looks fine - the connection will get closed when the outer `using` collapses. Yet there's that phrasing that I shouldn't do so.

Is the snippet above using the two classes together correctly? Should I expect any problems?

Comment: What you have should close the connection.  The point of the warning is the inner using will not close the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your intention should be to keep the connection living, and pass the connection to all the methods, open it at the beginning and close it at the end, in order to improve the proformance, it's fine, but looks cumbersome. and the "connection" will be passed around, even be referenced by the business logic layer.

Maybe you should find a better approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this generated DataContext class:

```
public partial class MyDataContext: System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
 ...
}
```

To use with a SqlConnection simple do this:

```
 using (var cnn = new SqlConnection("my connection string"))
 {
     cnn.Open();

     var dc= new MyDataContext(cnn);
     // enjoy
     ...
     cnn.Close();
 }
```